# What time does a bar mitzvah come into effect?

Tags: halacha, zemanim, bar-bas-bat-mitzvah

At what halachic time does a boy having his bar mitzvah become *chayav b'mitzvot*? It seems to me that the most likely times are either *shkia* or *tzeit*.

Comment: Would you agree that during Bein haShemashot he is a Safek? How is this different than any other "when does day end and night begin" sort of question (eg. date of Brit Milah, start of Shabbat, etc.)

Comment: It certainly might be analogous to Brit milah, an argument of which i wasn't aware. As for Shabbat, i know that we're stricter about that than other things.

Comment: Presumably since we are lenient with rabbinic mitzvahs and strict with torah ones, perhaps it depends what he wants to do. I.e. If he wants to say kiddush for everyone, would probably need to rule strictly and wait until dark. Something rabbinic, can be lenient and wait until shkiya...

Comment: Perhaps during Bein Hashmashos he is not yet Mechuyav since he doesn't yet have the חזקה שהביא שתי שערות. It would have to be a ודאי first day of his 14th year to be עוקר the חזקה of him not having שתי שערות.

Comment: You might have thought this is a theoretical question but it actually was very relevant to us this Hanuka. I had to travel on the first night and my older son was becoming bar mitzva that night. So he lit for the whole family, his first real mitzva and we waited until tzeit hakochavim.

Comment: There's a dispute in the rishonim about whether this happens at the beginning of the day or whether it requires מעת לעת (i.e. it happens at the exact time of day the boy was born)

Answer (score 3):

This is a matter of dispute among the *acharonim*. For example, in [Shulchan Aruch O.C. 53:10](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x420), [R. Moses Isserles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_Isserles) writes that someone who will turn 13 on Shabbat should not lead the Friday night services because at that point he is not yet 13:

> ובמקומות שלא נהגו כן אין לקטן לעבור לפני התיבה אפילו בתפלת ערבית אפילו הגיע לכלל י"ג שנים ביום השבת אין להתפלל ערבית של שבת דהרי עדיין אין לו י"ג שנה

Commenting on this, [R. Abraham Gombiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avraham_Gombiner) explains that this is because we pray before night actually begins, thus the kid is still a minor. But if we would pray after it is already actually night then the kid can lead the services:

> פי' דבמדינתנו מתפללין ערבית מבע"י והוא לא נכנס בשנת י"ד עד תחילת ליל שבת שהוא יום שנולד בו אבל אם מתפללים ערבית בלילה מותר לעבור לפני התיבה

According to this, the *Bar Mitzvah* takes effect the moment the kid's birthday begins, i.e. when the previous night begins. However, [R. Naftali Tzvi Yehuda Berlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naftali_Zvi_Yehuda_Berlin) disagrees with this. In his [commentary to Berachot 2a](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40994&st=&pgnum=7) he cites the Talmud's question as a refutation of R. Abraham Gombiner's view. The Talmud asks why the Mishnah first discusses the time for the nighttime recitation of *Shema* and then discusses the time for the daytime recitation of *Shema*; it should discuss the daytime *Shema* first. But, says R. Berlin, if R. Gombiner is correct then this question makes no sense. Of course the Mishnah would discuss the nighttime *Shema* first because that obligation occurs before the obligation of the daytime *Shema*, since every person becomes 13 at night. From the fact that the Talmud asks this question, then, we can infer that the *Bar Mitzvah* does **not** take effect when night begins; rather, it goes by the time that the person was born:

> מכאן יש ראיה להפוסקים דשני גדלות תליא משעה לשעה ודלא כהמג"א וסייעתו בסי' נ"ג ס"ק י"ג דתליא בריש מעל"ע דאם כן מאי מקשה הא סדר החיוב כך הוא תחילה של ערבית ואח"כ של שחרית אלא מוכח דבתר שעה אזלינן והדברים עתיקים

Comment: While interesting, it seems likely the OP was asking according to the MA opinion and just wondering how that is calculated practically.

Comment: @DoubleAA You mean he just wants to know at what point the next day begins?

Comment: That's what I thought above in my comment. I'm also a bit confused. Perhaps we can say better when we can assume for these purposes the next date has begun. There are different kinds of Tzes etc. and it isn't 100% obvious a priori anyway that the beginning of night for nighttime Mitzvot is the same as the beginning of the next calendar day.

Comment: @DoubleAA I agree with that comment, then.

Comment: @DoubleAA Judging by [his follow-up question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/63850/bar-mitzvah-boy-joining-a-zimun-on-the-night-of-his-bar-mitzvah-having-started) you're probably right.